# Python, handle exceptions caused by file ran by other file in the other file?

Tags: python, exception

I am making a python program (A) that runs another file (B). If B exits with code 0, A exits too. However, if B crashes, i want to handle that exception myself in A.

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549300/handle-exception-when-running-python-script-from-another-python-script) that asks the same thing, however, the one asking only needs the exit code or the error message printed to stderr. However, i want the raw data otherwise provided by [sys.exc_info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) if the exception occured in the parent / main file (A).

Comment: Have you considered using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module?

Comment: @alfinkel24 I want to, but python handles the exception itself rather than A doing it. So therefore i can't handle the exception in A. If there is any way to handle exceptions in A using subprocess, please tell me, I've only tried subproces.run("python", B)

Comment: Have you tried it with the `check=True` option?  From the documentation: `If check is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a CalledProcessError exception will be raised. Attributes of that exception hold the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr if they were captured.`.  As in `subprocess.run("python", B, check=True)`.

Comment: @alfinkel24 It works, thank you. Python still prints the stacktrace tho, is there any way to stop that too? I want to print it myself.

Comment: You can redirect STDERR to /dev/null in B.py. ref: the accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735917/redirecting-stdout-to-nothing-in-python but instead of sys.stdout you'd set sys.stderr.

Comment: Answer updated below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) with the `check=True` option:

From the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
If check is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a 
CalledProcessError exception will be raised. Attributes of that 
exception hold the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr if 
they were captured.
```

If B.py is something like:

```py
print("HELLO from B")
raise Exception("MEH")
```

Then A.py could be something like:

```py
import subprocess

try:
    print("TRYING B.py")
    subprocess.run(["python", "B.py"], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print("OH WELL: Handling exception from B.py")
    print(f"Exception from B: {cpe}")
```

The result:

```
~ > python A.py
TRYING B.py
HELLO from B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise Exception("MEH")
Exception: MEH
OH WELL: Handling exception from B.py
Exception from B: Command '['python', 'B.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

To silence the exception from display, change B.py to the following:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
print("HELLO from B")
raise Exception("MEH")
```

The result:

```
~ > python A.py
TRYING B.py
HELLO from B
OH WELL: Handling exception from B.py
Exception from B: Command '['python', 'B.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```