# how to abort python process on memory allocation failure

Tags: python, out-of-memory

Python may raise out-of-memory MemoryError exception but is there a way to just let the process terminate if malloc() return NULL?

I'm using some third-party python program do not want the program to handle MemoryError, just want the process to exit fast.

So what I'm looking for is some approach to let the python runtime terminate directly without issuing an memory-error exception.

Comment: try..except.. finally ?

Comment: I mean let the process die automatically without code change

Comment: use context manager

Comment: What `malloc`? There is no `malloc` in Python

Comment: @tristan: If you don't catch the `MemoryError` exception, surely your process will "just die automatically"?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057576/how-to-deal-with-memoryerror-in-python-code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `MemoryError` commonly means that the interpreter has run out of memory to allocate for the program (function) executing.  We both know that `MemoryErrors` are usually an indication that there is likely an issue within your code base.

I'm going to assume that you have a greedy piece of code that is robbing you of memory.

As mentioned in the comments and in Teddy's answer you can catch the MemoryError and exit the program.

```
import sys

try:
    # your greedy piece of code 

except MemoryError:
    sys.exit()
```

Another option would be to explicitly use `garbage collection`, which might help curtail the `MemoryError`. By using `gc.collect` you are forcing the garbage collector to release unreferenced memory.

```
import gc 

# your greedy piece of code 
gc.collect()
```

Another option would to look at limiting the CPU usage for your application, which might alleviate the `MemoryError`.

Here are the references:

- Python [signal](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/signal.html)
- Python [resource](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/resource.html)

And here is some sample code that can be modified.

```
import signal 
import resource 
import os 
 
# checking time limit exceed 
def time_exceeded(signo, frame): 
    print("Time's up !") 
    raise SystemExit(1) 
 
def set_max_runtime(seconds): 
    # setting up the resource limit 
    soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU) 
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (seconds, hard)) 
    signal.signal(signal.SIGXCPU, time_exceeded) 
 
# max run time of 15 millisecond 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    set_max_runtime(15) 
    while True: 
        pass
```

Without knowing more about your code troubleshooting this problem isn't easy.

For example, maybe the issue is related to a function calling a dataset that is too large to be processed in a loop

or maybe adding some threading to the function would resolve the `MemoryError`

There are lots of unknowns...

Based on my comment about calling your problematic script from another script.  I looked into this and discovered this [answer by 0xPrateek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549300/handle-exception-when-running-python-script-from-another-python-script)

`0xPrateek` suggested this:

```
import os

result = os.system('python other_script.py')
if 0 == result:
    print(" Command executed successfully")
else:
    print(" Command didn't executed successfully")
```

and this:

```
# Importing subprocess 
import subprocess

# Your command 
cmd = "python other_script.py"

# Starting process
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE.PIPE)

# Getting the output and errors of the program
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

# Printing the errors 
print(stderr)
```

I'm unsure how his code will work in your environment, but it is worth a try.

I have been trying to reproduce a `MemoryErrors` issue on my Mac. When my example doesn't use the exception `MemoryErrors` it exits fine from the other script.  If I use the exception things become hairy and makes my MAC unstable.

*Is the third party script that you cannot modify public?*

Comment: Very informed answer, nice.

Comment: actually, I cannot modify the python program

Comment: @tristan thanks for this info. How are you executing this python program?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I start the program like 'python /path/to/program'

Comment: @tristan how long after you start the program does the memory error happen? Is it random or does it happen at a specific timeframe?

Comment: it happens at random and basically my goal is to let the program die. maybe python doesn't support that

Comment: @tristan Have you tried to call the problem script from another script?  When the problem script throws the `MemoryError` the other script should exit.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to exit by letting your program throw a MemoryException you could do:

```
try:
    # your code
except MemoryError:
    exit()
```

or

```
try:
    # your code
except MemoryError:
    quit()
```

or

```
import sys

try:
    # your code
except MemoryError:
    sys.exit()
```

or if you really want to exit as fast as possible while still catching the error you can do:

```
import os

try:
    # your code
except MemoryError:
    os._exit(1)
```

This will directly call the C function _exit.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to exit the code using `sys.exit()` after detecting a `MemoryError`.

Like this below:

```
import sys

try:
    raise MemoryError
except MemoryError:
    sys.exit()
```